# MSSSMS SQL code returning zero in calculated field, but should be non zero result

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a calculated field [percentage unsold]. It is equal to [property units unsold]/[Property units].

This is the code:

```
select

scheme.SchemeID
,Property.PropertyID
,property.Units [Property Units]
,count(SaleStatus.Description) [Property Units Unsold]
,count(SaleStatus.Description)/property.Units [percentage Unsold]
,property.PVNetRent
,property.PVNetRent
from scheme

inner join property on scheme.schemeid=property.schemeid
inner join unit on property.propertyid= unit.property
full outer join SaleStatus on unit.HandoverStatus = SaleStatus.SaleStatusID
where scheme.SchemeID = 336401
group by 

scheme.SchemeID
,Property.PropertyID
,property.Units
,property.PVNetRent
```

and these are my results:

[image]

Why is my percentage unsold 0 when I would expect to see 0.75 in record 1 and 0.5 in record 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your database does integer division.  I find the simplest solution is to multiply by `1.0` *before the division*:

```
count(SaleStatus.Description) * 1.0 / property.Units as [percentage Unsold]
```

Comment: @DasalKalubowila you need to multiply  by 1.0 not 1